# Highlighting jQuery datepicker date

Tags: jquery, css, datepicker

Using **jQuery Datepicker**, related to this page http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html
I want to highlight specify dates given by array

```
ex: array("2012-12-24" => "red", "2012-12-24" => "green")
```

How get this approach.

My poor code

```
<style type="text/css">
    @import"jquery.datepick.css";
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.datepick.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#popupDatepicker').datepick();
        $('#inlineDatepicker').datepick({
            onSelect: showDate
        });
    });

    function showDate(date) {
        alert('The date chosen is ' + date);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>A popup datepicker
        <input type="text" id="popupDatepicker">
    </p>
    <p>Or inline</p>
    <div id="inlineDatepicker"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also try Kendo UI. It has a Calendar widget and the DatePicker widget which takes an array of dates, from that it will be easy to customize the template of the widget.

[Kendo UI - Calendar](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/calendar/template.html)

Comment: Kendo UI Web is free, the Calendar and Datepicker is part of the Web package.

Comment: If you can put more details about "Kendo UI Web" please put here.As a link or article like that.Thanks.

Comment: The download page for the Kendo UI says that the Web package is Open Source (GPL v3). http://www.kendoui.com/download.aspx

You can find all the demos here: http://demos.kendoui.com/web/overview/index.html

And the documentation: http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/ui

I'm currently using this framework with my thesis and I've been very happy with it, you can also buy the DataViz package for business charts. Although I didn't try it yet, but it looks good.

Comment: i down loaded that and fullfilled my task but there is complex content and difficult to choose what are the necessary  and unnecessary ex: there is folder called 'style' but datepicker calender need only it's styles\Default\sprites.png

Comment: pls can you give an idea to edit http://demos.kendoui.com/web/calendar/template.html templete.html code using above down loaded things.

Comment: @user1822719 - Have you tried modifying the month.content property of the widget? If you have complex styling to be applied in your widget then you should define a template for the widget to use. It's all about your CSS from there (classes), you can have conditions (if/else statements) in your template so that you can achieve the desired look.

Comment: sorry i cant find those file    <script src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="source/kendo.all.js"></script>
    <link href="styles/kendo.common.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="styles/kendo.default.css" rel="stylesheet" /> on that demo can i down load those seperatly

Comment: The property I'm talking about is part of the widget already, when you init a Calendar widget you will have the option to modify it from there. Check this snippet I made. http://jsfiddle.net/ud984/

Comment: sorry i cant get you.http://demos.kendoui.com/web/calendar/template.html this link have some code.but icant find its linked file     <link href="styles/kendo.common.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="styles/kendo.default.css" rel="stylesheet" />. if you can supply down load link to kendo.default.css,kendo.common.css file thanks again.further its day assigning was recurcive how prevent it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try below one with your code base.(this is a sample)

**CSS**

```
.Highlighted a{
   background-color : Green !important;
   background-image :none !important;
   color: White !important;
   font-weight:bold !important;
   font-size: 12pt;
}
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var SelectedDates = {};
    SelectedDates[new Date('12/25/2012')] = new Date('12/25/2012');
    SelectedDates[new Date('05/04/2012')] = new Date('05/04/2012');
    SelectedDates[new Date('06/06/2012')] = new Date('06/06/2012');

    $('#txtDate').datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var Highlight = SelectedDates[date];
            if (Highlight) {
                return [true, "Highlighted", Highlight];
            }
            else {
                return [true, '', ''];
            }
        }
    });
});​
```

**UPDATE 1**

Working Example [**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/cqf9d/213/)

**Jquery document** says there having **"beforeShowDay:" Option**.

Check [**Datepicker Widget API**](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

**UPDATE 2 :**

You can refer jquery by using Google CDN like below.So Commented out your jquery references and get like below.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
            type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE 3 :**

Below I have mentioned **only  pseudo code**.Change it according to Jquery syntax.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#txtDate').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {

      //according to the date you have to decide which css should load.
        var Highlight = SelectedDates[date];
        var yourColor = whichColor(SelectedDates[date]);

        if (Highlight  && yourColor =='red') {
            return [true, "RedHighlighted", Highlight];
        }
        else if (Highlight   && yourColor =='green') {
             return [true, "GreenHighlighted", Highlight];
        }
        else {
            return [true, '', ''];
        }
    }
});


//return a color according to your date logic
 function whichColor(dateArray) { 

      return color;
   }
```

});​

For more information check [**Highlight Specific Dates in jQuery UI DatePicker**](http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2012/05/highlight-specific-dates-in-jquery-ui.html)

I hope this will help to you.

Comment: the case is there is no such a function beforeShowDay in jquery.datepick.js how to overcome this i show this solution on a web but not work for me

Comment: @user1822719 I have updated my post with working example on jsfiddler check that.

Comment: @user1822719 Jquery document says there having "beforeShowDay:" Option.Check my update section for more details.

Comment: ok i get you,but i don't understand how to get jsfiddler source in to my page because of jquery.datepick.js do the bad things.pls give me an down load link to the  jsfiddler source's like jQuery UI 1.8.18 file or some else

Comment: @user1822719 OK. May be your jquery version is old one.Try to use like I showed on Update 2.

Comment: how to higlight with different colour refering such a array("2012-12-24"=>"red","2012-12-27"=>"green")

Comment: @user1822719 check my UPDATE 3 :.

Comment: Hi @Sampath I tried your solution in my project but I'm getting this error. **TypeError: daySettings[2].replace is not a function** Please help how can I overcome this problem? I even try to use the newer version of jquery UI but then my datepicker didn't even showed on page.

Answer (score 0):

Use `onDate` callback to achieve the goal.

Example: Click "Day-by-day" Tab > National days (CSS) to view the demo

http://keith-wood.name/calendarsPicker.html

```
$('#nationalPicker').calendarsPicker({ 
    onDate: nationalDays,
    showTrigger: '#calImg'}); 

var natDays = [[1, 26, 'au'], [2, 6, 'nz'], [3, 17, 'ie'], [4, 27, 'za'], 
    [5, 25, 'ar'], [6, 6, 'se'], [7, 4, 'us'], [8, 17, 'id'], 
    [9, 7, 'br'], [10, 1, 'cn'], [11, 22, 'lb'], [12, 12, 'ke']]; 

function nationalDays(date, inMonth) { 
    if (inMonth) { 
        for (i = 0; i < natDays.length; i++) { 
            if (date.month() == natDays[i][0] && date.day() == natDays[i][1]) { 
                return {dateClass: natDays[i][2] + '_day', selectable: false}; 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    return {}; 
}
```

Reference: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/highlight-multiple-dates-on-keith-wood-jquery-datepick-plugin